# regarding saving values in database in android

Tags: android

I am creating a sample application using shared preference.I have 3 edittext,2 Buttons,I want to save data in database of android stimulator.How can i do it.Can anybody tell me.Thanks in advance......

Comment: do you want to store them in a DB or in the shared preferences?

Comment: in databse and show ....Ninja whats ur email id

Answer (score 0):

try something like this to store values

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = quasiprefer.edit();
        editor.putString("password", "");
        editor.putString("question", "");
        editor.commit();
```

and to retrieve back values

```
SharedPreferences prefer = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String saveQuestion = prefer .getString("question", "");
    String saveAnswer = prefer .getString("answer", "");
```

Comment: Saurabh can u tell me steps how to install an apk file in android stimulator????I will be very thankful to you,,,,,,,,

Comment: open cmd prompt browse through the directory of you Drive:\android-sdk-windows\tools 
then give command "apk install "full path of apk" your emulator must be running already for this http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/installing-apk-files-on-android-device-emulator/

Comment: saurabh whats ur email id..I want to be in touch with you